# How to cite organizations properly?

Tags: biblatex, acronyms, organisation

while there have been similar questions, mine have not been answered yet.

I am using `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}` to cite my sources.

My paper cites a lot of organizations, UN Women, World Bank, UNICEF, and the like. Using Zotero, I have exported the corresponding Bibtex files and added the to my reference list. Multiple problems have occurred using `\autocite`:

1. For example, *UN Women* is always cited as *United Nations Entity for Gender Equality and the Empowerment of Women*. While that is the correct title, this heavily affects the flow of reading and I only want it to be written out the first time it is cited, afterwards it should be written as *UN Women* only. Same for the other organizations and other sources from UN Women.
2. Titles like the one above are only cited as *(for Gender Equality & the Empowerment of Women)* if no curly brackets are added to the author in the Bibtex source. As many organizations with long names are quoted within my theses, manually going through all citation keys would be very tedious, is there a way to solve this?

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If you search this site for "corporate author", you'll find several postings that discuss how to tell bibtex (or biblatex/biber) that a given author is "corporate".

Answer (score 1):

1. With the APA style, this is automatic as long as you have the full author in the `author` field and the short form in the `shortauthor` field.
2. You should usually put the full `author` field for group authors like this in braces so that they are not parsed as a normal name.

See examples 8.7d in the APA style documentation and data file:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf (page 6)

https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-citations.bib